# Alternative scopes for 'read' and 'client' in slack API

Tags: slack, slack-api

As slack has deprecated the scopes 'read' and 'client', I want to know are there any other alternative scopes for this?
I want to call https://slack.com/api/team.prefs.get API

Comment: Hi, Can you provide more info about the API that you want to use? Any url or response that you expect from the API.

Comment: I want to fetch all the administrative settings in workspace setting tab.

Answer (score 0):

the `team.prefs.get` method is a hidden method, it's not currently supported and it's not recommended you used it. There's also no available scopes that will allow you to call this method. If you're on an Enterprise team you can try calling`admin.teams.settings.info` otherwise,`team.info` might be the only other alternative.